# Gayatri mantra mental recitation

Tags: gayatri-mantra, japa

Are there any adverse effects if mistakes made in mental reciting of gayatri mantra while doing daily chores?

Comment: Are you talking about mistakes in pronunciation or something else?

Comment: Regular work doesn't effect if you are chanting mantras by oral or else mental reciting. If you made mistakes intentionally in any other forms/object, definitely it will effect your daily works in any other forms.

Comment: @Rickross yes sir pronunciation and incomplete chanting, missing some words like that.